# Django How can I roll back or retrieve data in fields?

Tags: django

I have a question in Django.

1. I renamed fields in my models.py on my editor.
2. After renaming the name of fields, I made makemigrations and did 'migrate' on cmd.
3. After 'migrate', I checked my database on DB broswer and I found that not only the name of fields changed, but the data of the fields also changed into the name of fields I just changed as just lowercased.

i.e.) Original name of field was ingredient and I changed the name to Essential_ingredient. I checked DB and turned out that all of data for the column of changed field is essential_field like picture.

[DB after renaming fields](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nfpny.png)

I posted this question on FB page and one said I can roll back(revert) by doing "migrate  ". So I tried it and then it turned out that the field came back correctly to purposedly migrated file, but the data of the field still haven't changed back yet.

[DB after reverting migration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/46COh.png)

I guess this problem happened because, when I renamed fields, I renamed two of them at the same time. I saw a comment on stackoverflow that I'm supposed rename the one field at a time, but this was after I'd changed names of fields.

Does any know any way solution like my situation? 
Thanks in advance.

+Edit)

[migrate 0011.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VCoQK.png)

[migrate 0012.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YsQ8Y.png)

[migrate 0013.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/isXEn.png)

Comment: Can you share the migration file?

Comment: @quick I just posted them. I'm not sure, but I think problem happened after migrate 0013.py where two fields got renamed at the same time.